# Unable to access AWS account through terraform AWS provider -- invalid AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

AWS noob here. I am unable to find where in the management console do we see the access token. I have access to the secret key and the access key but apparently API access to AWS requires an access token as well which I am unable to find anywhere on the portal

***Additional Information***:
What I am looking for, is a way to create and destroy tokens via the management console provided by AWS. I am actually learning about terraform AWS provider which requires access key, secret key and the token.

Scraping the internet for answers, it becomes clear that one create and destroy these tokens using the SDK. I am looking at an easy and quick way to create this token ***via the management console itself***. Is that even possible?

Accessing the AWS resource without a token gives me the following error:

```
aws_instance.sl-ec2-01: Creating...
╷
│ Error: creating EC2 Instance: InvalidAMIID.NotFound: The image id '[ami-07ffb2f4d65357b42]' does not exist
│       status code: 400, request id: 53057722-210e-46fa-89e3-2484f35ab263
│
│   with aws_instance.sl-ec2-01,
│   on ec2-instance.tf line 1, in resource "aws_instance" "sl-ec2-01":
│    1: resource "aws_instance" "sl-ec2-01" {
```

this is the exact ami that I retrieved from the portal. My terraform code snippet for provisioning a new VM in the ap-south-1 region:

```
resource "aws_instance" "sl-ec2-01" {
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    ami = "ami-07ffb2f4d65357b42"
}
```

***Update 2:***
It turns out I had not changed the region information which is why the AMI was not matching. It has now spun an image correctly.

Comment: What is the API you are trying to access and how (through SDK or your own code)? An access key/secret is usually enough to sign an API request.

Comment: I am looking for a way to create this token via the management console and not through any SDK (for now)

Comment: The AMI simply does not exist. Make sure you are using the correct region and that the AMI ID has in fact that ID in the region of interest.

Comment: Ok my bad I hadn't change the region portion in the terraform code

Comment: Did that solve your issue?

Comment: Please post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

An IAM User only has an **Access Key** and a **Secret Key**.

However, if you create **temporary credentials** using the AWS Security Token Service (STS), then **a token is also provided**.

For example, using your IAM User credentials to call `AssumeRole()` to gain privileges from an IAM Role, then you will be given:

- Access Key
- Secret Key
- Access Token

Comment: I am looking for a way to create this token via the management console and not through any SDK (for now). I've tried to log in as the root user but I still couldn't find the token for that user

Comment: _WHY_ do you wish to create it? It is not required for normal usage. It only exists for temporary credentials, and the token will be provided to you when you create the temporary credentials.

Comment: may be that is what I should be looking for, temporary credentials. I am learning about the terraform AWS provider which needs the token along with the access and secret keys

Comment: Then please update your question with this information and please be _specific_ about where/why you need it. Note that [Docs overview | hashicorp/aws | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs) says that the **token is _optional_**.

Comment: I've changed my question and made it more precise by showing the exact error thrown by the AWS terraform provider

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the AMI (machine image) corresponding to a particular OS flavor changes from region to region. While I had changed my region, I hadn't changed the AMI. Which is what I was erring with.

Upon changing the AMI for the OS to the one for my new region, it worked